# Are triangulations of compact manifolds PL homeomorphic?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes, triangulations, combinatorial-topology

I have frequently come across the statement "Any two triangulations of a compact n-manifold are related by bistellar moves" attributed to Pachner via Lickorish's paper 'Simplicial moves on complexes and manifolds'. The theorem this refer to is the following: Closed combinatorial n-manifolds are PL homeomorphic if and only if they are bistellar equivalent.

My question is: Considering that Hauptvermutung is not true for manifolds of dimension more than 3, how can we justify this statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pachner‘s Theorem is about PL-homeomorphic manifolds, while the Hauptvermutung is asking for a PL-homeomorphism between manifolds which a priori are only homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks ThiKu for your reply. Perhaps I should reframe my question: How do I show that any two simplicial triangulations of a compact manifold have a common refinement? As simplicial complexes in some R^n the two triangulations may have different supports.

Comment: If you are asking for a proof of Pachner‘s Theorem, the reference is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669813800807

Comment: If you want to know why Pachner moves yield triangulations with common refinements, that should hopefully be some elementary exercise, though I‘ve checked it only in dimension 3.

Comment: And if you want to know why there can be triangulations of a compact manifold which are not PL-homeomorphic, this has been done by Casson-Sullivan via surgery theory: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-3343-4_6

Comment: I'd like to know why triangulations of a compact manifold which are not PL homomorphic, are related by pachner moves.

Comment: They are not. Pachner's Theorem is only true für PL-homeomorphic manifolds.

Comment: Thanks ThiKu for all your replies. So this off-hand statement that I've read in several papers is false.

Comment: Perhaps those papers were referring to special dimensions. For 2- and 3-dimensional manifolds, every homeomorphism class contains a unique PL-structure. (Moise‘s Theorem, see https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781461299080 ). Thus in that case triangulation of homeomorphic manifolds are related via Pachner moves.